# my server unable to reach https port 443 urls behind proxy

Tags: proxy

I have set up a 12.04 LTS ubuntu headless server 64 bit.

This is my network interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The basic eth0 network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp


# static IP
iface eth0 inet static
   address 146.11.90.234
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 146.11.90.1
   dns-nameservers 146.11.115.200
```

I can do ping www.google.com from inside the server. However, I am unable to access https repositories when I try to use composer.

I know the proxy server allows me to use all protocols via www.xxxx.com:8080

Please advise.

Comment: Sometimes corporate environments with access to internet via a proxy may have a poorly (read: very slow) setup to access HTTPS links. In my case I had to avoid setting up the browsers using the automatic `*.pac` script, but use http://www.whatismyproxy.com/ or similar to detect the exact proxy server and ports used, and then configure the browsers manually to use that.

Comment: Have you thought about a HTTP tunnel but it needs a machine from outside (At home or a VPS ....)

Comment: is it a HTTP proxy? if yes, when you said 'pingable', it's confusing as it's not possible ICMP packets go over a HTTP tunnel. sounds like ping is going thru firewall directly, but true? not quite. apart from this, different client application may have different individual settings when accessing thru proxy, not all rely on system settings, or environment variables (http_proxy, https_proxy). so read the application manual on how to configure proxy might help.

Comment: Can you access HTTPS via a normal desktop browser? Can you try lynx in your headless server and see if it gets the response?

Answer (score 0):

In order for an SSL proxy to work, the proxy has to install its own SSL certificate in the user’s browser and have the client establish a secure and encrypted session with the proxy, which in turn establishes a secure and encrypted session w/ the server on its behalf. Very often SSL proxies are set up incorrectly or proxy only works with 80 port but SSL traffic is sent directly - without proxy. So you can try to access SSL site directly.